# int cannot be dereferenced while sorting list by Integer property

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have a 2D array and I populate it to an ArrayList of type Segment (a class I'm already defined). I want to sort the Arraylist based on the second element in each object in ascending order. I've checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396804/sorting-an-arraylistarraylistinteger-by-the-third-element-in-the-arraylisti) which uses comparable class to sort it but it doesn't work with me and it gives me the

> int cannot be dereferenced

error.

Below is my code

*note that `object.getR()` gives me the middle element in each object. For example, the object of type segment `x= (6,8,4)` then `x.gerR()` gives me the value 8.*

```
int[][] input = {
    {0, 3, 3}, {3,5,2}, {6,8,4}, {9,11,3}, {2,4,4}, {5,6,3}, {7,8,3},{9,12,1}
};

ArrayList<Segment> data = new ArrayList<>();

for (int[] input1 : input) {
    data.add(new Segment(input1[0], input1[1], input1[2]));
}
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<Segment>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Segment lhs, Segment rhs) {
        return lhs.getR().compareTo(rhs.getR());
    }
});
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work with me" how exactly it doesn't work for you? Are you getting error/exception/different results than expected (like ascending order instead of descending one)?

Comment: Please post the actual error message you are seeing.

Comment: your issue has no relation with sorting. It is a compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int cannot be dereferenced` suggest that `getR()` returns `int` not `Integer` (despite what your title suggests). `int` is *primitive* type so it doesn't have any methods like `compareTo`. Easiest way to compare int values is by `Integer.compare(a, b)` (by default it returns result according to ascending order, if you want to get result for descending order `Integer.compare(b, a)`).

So change

```
return lhs.getR().compareTo(rhs.getR());
```

to

```
return Integer.compare(lhs.getR(), rhs.getR());
```

---

BTW since Java 8 we can use Lambdas and method references. Also lists now have `sort(Comparator)` method which allows us to write code like:

```
data.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Segment::getR));
```

instead of

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<Segment>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Segment lhs, Segment rhs) {
        return Integer.compare(lhs.getR(), rhs.getR());
    }
});
```